# Impinj Speedway reader does not enable antenna

Tags: rfid

I am testing a Speedway reader 420 with a guard minirail antenna connected to Port 1.

The problem is that I cannot get this to work. When I telnet to the Speedway reader, and issue the "show rfid stat" command, I get this status:

```
 > show rfid stat
Status='0,Success'
LastStatisticReset='4024'
ReaderOperationalStatus='enabled'
ReaderAdministrativeStatus='enabled'
Antenna1AdministrativeStatus='enabled'
Antenna2AdministrativeStatus='enabled'
Antenna3AdministrativeStatus='enabled'
Antenna4AdministrativeStatus='enabled'
Antenna1OperationalStatus='disabled'
Antenna2OperationalStatus='disabled'
Antenna3OperationalStatus='disabled'
Antenna4OperationalStatus='disabled'
```

I think this is the problem. Antenna1OperationalStatus appears disabled.

Any help about this, please?
Thanks

Jaime

Comment: What's the status of your configuration bits?

Comment: what? I am not sure what you mean with that,

Comment: I'm not familiar with this specific device, but usually there is some form of configuration required before the device actually functions. It does not automatically detect the antenna, so you'll have to tell the device to turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

I happend to me yesterday.
In my case was the physical antenna connection.

Try monitoring the antenna status while you sloooowly plug the antenna. In my case I got it connected with 4 turns, no less, no more. After realizing that it was the plug, I just needed to replace it.

I hope it helps. I took me 0.5 day of work to figure it out.